# Value provided in ExpressionAttributeNames unused in expressions: keys: {#loan}

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to query for an Asset item and filter it only if it is on loan. An asset is considered not on loan if the loan attribute does not exists or is null. Querying for the item via the CLI works as intended. The documentClient.query() however throws the error:

NodeJS:

```
documentClient.query({
  TableName: "Asset",
  ProjectionExpression: "id",
  KeyConditionExpression: "#id = :id",
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#id": "id",
      "#loan": "loan"
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":id": "8b8ea8f5-196f-440c-aff3-87ab66eb9669",
      ":null": null
  },
  FilterExpresssion: "attribute_exists(#loan) and #loan <> :null"
}, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err); // ---> error thrown
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});

ValidationException: Value provided in ExpressionAttributeNames unused in expressions: keys: {#loan}
```

CLI:

```
// values.json  
{
    ":id":{"S":"8b8ea8f5-196f-440c-aff3-87ab66eb9669"},
    ":null":{"NULL":true}
}

aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name Asset \
    --projection-expression "id" \
    --key-condition-expression "#id = :id" \
    --expression-attribute-names '{"#id": "id", "#loan": "loan"}' \
    --expression-attribute-values file://values.json \
    --filter-expression "attribute_exists(#loan) and #loan <> :null"

{
    "Items": [],
    "Count": 0,
    "ScannedCount": 1,
    "ConsumedCapacity": null
}
```

The schema of the Asset table:

```
Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
TableName: Asset
Properties:
    AttributeDefinitions:
        -
          AttributeName: "id"
          AttributeType: "S"
    KeySchema: 
        - 
          AttributeName: "id"
          KeyType: "HASH"
    BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
    ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 0
          WriteCapacityUnits: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way?

```
ExpressionAttributeValues = { ":null", new AttributeValue { NULL = true } }
```

Cheers